# Why can't I compare 404 with return of (.getMessage e)?

Tags: clojure

I am clearly not understanding what (.getMessage e) returns, and that is probably why I am having the following problem shown in the following block of code (part of a let binding).

```
accumail-results (try
  (client/get accumail-url {:query-params (into {} (first one-parsed-csv-vec))})
  (catch Exception e
  (println (.getMessage e))
  (if (not (= (.getMessage e) 404))
    (exit-sys (str accmail-except-str (.getMessage e) )))))
```

I have tried setting the values to strings and comparing those, and I get null pointer errors. So, why can't I compare the output of (.getMessage e) with 404. I know I am getting back a 404 from my web application.

Comment: Please post a simple, complete example clearly demonstrating the problem, including input, output, and errors.  Removing dependencies will make it easier to correctly find the problem.  You say `I have tried setting the values to strings and comparing those, and I get null pointer errors` -- please show us; post this code along with the errors you get.  Also, doesn't `.getMessage` return a String?  That won't compare equal to a number.

Comment: You have the code. It performs an exit-sys when the return code is 404. I want to know why it won't compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` is just a Java exception. [Exception.getMessage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage%28%29) returns a string, which will never compare equal to the number 404.

If the exception is wrapping an HTTP error response code, then you'll need more specialized knowledge about the specific exception type to know how to get the code out of the exception. It could be made available as a method on the Exception subclass, or you might have to parse it out of the message. How you get at the error code will depend on what HTTP client you're using and how it represents errors.